# How do I return records where the sum of a column that corresponds to a specific user ID is greater than 1M?

Tags: sql, db2

My scenario is as follows -

I have these records in my DB table (Table name:  MyTable):

```
ID                                      ACCOUNT_NUM     DATE        BALANCE
------------------------------------    -----------     ----------  -----------
111                                     1               2020-12-17  500000.0000
111                                     2               2020-12-17  500000.0000
222                                     1               2020-12-17  500000.0000
222                                     2               2020-12-17  400000.0000
333                                     1               2020-12-17  800000.0000
333                                     2               2020-12-17  300000.0000
444                                     1               2020-12-17  1000000.0000
444                                     2               2020-12-17  100.0000
```

Each ID represents a member and each member has 2 accounts.

I need to return only the records which have an aggregated balance of over 1000000.00 (1M) by adding account 1 and 2 for each ID.

Ive tried this so far:

```
SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUM, DATE, BALANCE FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, ACCOUNT_NUM, DATE, BALANCE 
HAVING SUM(BALANCE) >= '1000000.00';
```

But it is only returning a single record for ID 444 where the account 1 balance is = 1M.

How can I get the query to SUM accounts 1 and 2 for each member and return if over 1M?

New to SQL. Please let me know if I need to add more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUM, DATE, BALANCE
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             SUM(BALANCE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ACCOUNT_NUM, DATE) as SUM_BALANCE
      FROM MyTable t
     ) t
WHERE SUM_BALANCE >= 1000000.00;
```

Your question suggests that you just want to do the sum by `account_num` but your current logic includes other columns.  I have basically included your current logic -- although it does not make sense to include `BALANCE` because that is what you are adding up.

Comment: This seems to be working. Now I'm trying to add another clause to only get DATE that falls within the last 90 days:
```
SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUM, DATE, BALANCE
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             SUM(BALANCE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ACCOUNT_NUM, DATE) as SUM_BALANCE
      FROM MyTable t
     ) t
WHERE SUM_BALANCE >= 1000000.00 AND DATE BETWEEN (CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) AND (CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY);
```

But it seems to be returning 0 rows. If I isolate that where clause of 90 days it returns the records i need...
See anything IM missing?

Comment: @AndrewHernandez . . . The `WHERE` clause actually looks correct.

Comment: I updated all records in the table to have date of 2020-12-18 which is inside the 90 day window not but for some reason only one record gets returned

`444                                     1               2020-12-18  1000000.0000`

 but there is more than just that row that aggregate to over 1M

I expect to get

Comment: @AndrewHernandez . . . `select dateadd(day, 90, '2020-12-18')` = 2021-03-18.  Depending on the time zone where you are running this, it might be March 19th.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to apply the necessary criteria.  In this example, as each row from the table (aliased as "t1") is evaluated, it will check against the sum total of all records in the table (aliased as "t2", via the sub-query) that have the same "ID" value

```
SELECT ID, ACCOUNT_NUM, DATE, BALANCE FROM MyTable t1
WHERE
(
    SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
) > 1000000.00
```

Comment: I do wonder, though, whether your actual table has multiple records for the same ID / Account Number, with different dates?  Is the table holding historical records of balances over time?

Comment: yes the table has daily records of each members account so it will have the same ID for different dates of each account 1 and 2

Comment: Where would I add the where clause to only get dates between 90 days ago from today and current date?

Comment: Hi Andrew, you'd need to add that criteria to both WHEREs - the one inside the sub-query and the main outer query.  So you'd add AND CONVERT(date, t2.[DATE]) >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())) after WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID, and you'd also add AND CONVERT(date, t1.[DATE]) >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())) after > 1000000.00